# What is Spree Deface::Override :original keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

In `Spree` `Deface::Override` what is :original keyword used for ? I am working on a apps not from the begining and I got struck with a code here:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "....",
                 :name => "admin_user_acct_sales_row",

                 :insert_bottom => "[data-hook='admin_users_index_rows'], #admin_users_index_rows[data-hook]",

                 :partial => "spree/admin/users/...",

                 :original => "90406d8cbc733e601bb9717b4b5711e43fe181a3",

                 :disabled => false)
```

Here `:original` stands for what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Following I found in the `spree/deface README`

```
:original - String containing original markup that is being overridden.
            If supplied Deface will log when the original markup changes, 
            which helps highlight overrides that need attention when 
            upgrading versions of the source application. Only really
            warranted for :replace overrides. NB: All whitespace is stripped
            before comparison.
```

For complete README, go to https://github.com/spree/deface

Hope it will help. Thanks.